# Using multiple states in a context's value, prevent re-rendering of components using states that haven't changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update various components in a dashboard with realtime data using a DataContext.
I'm using multiple states in the context's value property, one for each set of values i want to update together.

When setting one state however, all components which use any state from DataContext get re-rendered. Some values get updated multiple times per second, resulting in very poor performance.

Here is an example:

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

var DataContext = React.createContext();

function DataProvider({ children }) {

  var [prop1State, setProp1State] = useState({test: 1});
  var [prop2State, setProp2State] = useState({test: 2});
  var [prop3State, setProp3State] = useState({test: 3});

  setInterval(() => {
    setProp2State(state => {
      return {test: state.test + 1}
    });
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(() => {
    setProp3State(state => {
      return {test: state.test + 1}
    });
  }, 2500);

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider
      value={{
        prop1: {
          get: prop1State,
          set: setProp1State
        },
        prop2: {
          get: prop2State,
          set: setProp2State
        },
        prop3: {
          get: prop1State,
          set: setProp1State
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

function SomeComponent(props) {

  console.log("Rendering SomeComponent");

  var dataContext = useContext(DataContext);

  return (
    <p>
      {dataContext.prop1.get.test}
    </p>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
        <SomeComponent/>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The page just shows 1, but the console is full of "Rendering SomeComponent", triggered by the setInterval's that only update 2 and 3.

Can this be solved **without** wrapping SomeComponent in 3 different Contexts, one for each state?
Is having say 10 nested contexts bad?
Is there a better alternative to contexts in this case?

Comment: Maybe you can try wrapping around `SomeComponent` in a memo. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Thanks, i've found something in the mean time: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156